# Mobile Apps Conversion Tracking and Remarketing API Always return False

Tags: google-api, google-remarketing-audience

I'm trying to report conversions to the Google Ads API, **but it always returns false**.

We have tried to notify all users who install our application in a country where we only have Google Ads advertising and it always returns false. We have verified that there are no other MMPs attributing for us (we have disconnected Appsflyer from our account)

This is the request form that we are sending

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/app/1.0?dev_token=[MY_DEV_TOKEN]&link_id=[MY_LINKID]&app_event_type=first_open&rdid=[ANDROID_USER_GAID]&id_type=advertisingid&lat=0&app_version=2.0.0&os_version=9.3.2&sdk_version=2.0.0&timestamp=1616661257&value=1.99&currency_code=USD' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
--header 'X-Forwarded-For: 216.58.194.174' \
--header 'User-Agent: MyAnalyticsCompany/1.0.0 (iOS 10.0.2; en_US; iPhone9,1; Build/13D15; Proxy)' \
--header 'Host: www.googleadservices.com' \
--header 'Content-Length: 0'
```

Following the format specified in the documentation
https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/api/request-response-specs

Has anyone had this problem? What am I doing wrong?
Regards!

Comment: Resolved, in the configuration panel you have to create the type of event that you are going to notify.

Comment: What ”configuration panel” do you mean? Could you be more specific please. Are you talking about the ”conversion” page inside google ads, or something else?